# cache googlemaps geocoding results but my code is broken

Tags: php, sql, google-maps, caching

I posted this question last night but I worded it wrong and didn't explain correctly. I am trying to cache googlemaps geocoding results for use in a firefighting mapping thing I have made and I am getting close to google's limits hence the need to cache the results. Help!

The code below kinda works however it creates a new sql record each time the code runs regardless of whether the address is already in the database. It seems to only call google once then saves the data, it then loads the data from the database ok and it looks like the rest works but I just can't see where I am going wrong.. As I said it creates a new record each and everytime the code runs and I would end up with a database full of the same identical records. My brain hurts but I really need to get this working so I can continue to help fire trucks to fires. :)

Oh, I am using the geocoding results on googlemaps (as permitted by the T&C) and this code is really only to get it working. I hope that makes sense and I hope someone can help... Thanks :)

```
<?php

$jobadd = "1000 BURWOOD HWY, BURWOOD";

// connect to the database
include('connect-db.php');

// get results from database and find needle
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM geocache") 
or die(mysql_error());  


while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
{
$needle =  '' . $row['address'] . '';

if (strpos($jobadd,$needle) !== false)
{
$status = "CACHED";
$latitude =  '' . $row['latitude'] . '';
$longitude =  '' . $row['longitude'] . '';
}

else

{
$status = "GOOGLE";
$address2 = "$jobadd, Victoria, Australia";
define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.google.com"); 
$base_url = "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/api/geocode/xml"; 
$request_url = $base_url . "?address=" . urlencode($address2) ."&sensor=false"; 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($request_url)); 

$latitude = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
$longitude = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng; 

// save the data to the database
mysql_query("INSERT geocache SET address='$jobadd', latitude='$latitude', longitude='$longitude' ")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
}

}

echo $status;
echo '<BR>';
echo $jobadd;
echo '<BR>';
echo 'LAT:';
echo $latitude;
echo '<BR>';
echo 'LON:';
echo $longitude;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to output the result of strpos? The logic does not look incorrect. The issue is in the if condition. What do the records look like in the DB?

Comment: The records all update and its seems to be reading the info from the database after the initial call to google to get the results if I refresh. I have been playing some more and it all seems to work ok if I use UPDATE instead of INSERT in the last SQLquery as it just updates the one sql record instead of creating a new record each time. However it is pointlessly updating the record with the same info eachtime the code runs. Again I hope I am making sense! I am trying to learn as I go and I a slow learner! LOL